# Watermark not drawing in image

Tags: c#, gdi+

I had an error come up:
A Graphics Object cannot be Created from an Image that has an Indexed Pixel Format

So I implemented this code into my method: [Solution for "A Graphics Object cannot be Created from an Image that has an Indexed Pixel Format"](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/solution-for-a-graphics-object-cannot-be-created-from-an-im/)

But now my watermark doesnt want to draw on my image.

Please can anyone assist.

Code:

```
private Image AddWaterMark(Image original)
{
    Image waterMark = Image.FromFile(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GalleryFolder"] + @"\watermark.png");
    Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)original;

    Size waterMarkResize = ResizeFit(new Size(original.Width, original.Height));

    using (Image watermarkImage = new Bitmap(waterMark, waterMarkResize))
    using (Graphics imageGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(new Bitmap(bm.Width, bm.Height)))
    {
        imageGraphics.DrawImage(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height), 0, 0, bm.Width, bm.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        using (TextureBrush watermarkBrush = new TextureBrush(watermarkImage))
        {
            int x = (original.Width / 2 - watermarkImage.Width / 2);
            int y = (original.Height / 2 - watermarkImage.Height / 2);
            watermarkBrush.TranslateTransform(x, y);
            imageGraphics.FillRectangle(watermarkBrush, new Rectangle(new Point(x, y), new Size(watermarkImage.Width + 1, watermarkImage.Height)));
        }
    }

    return bm;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What if you change that watermarkBrush into a plain white (or black) brush? Do you see something then?

Comment: No errors. It saves the image but without the watermark. Tried with the black and white brush still nothing is created on the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're creating a new `Bitmap` to pass to `Graphics.FromImage` then returning the uneditted original `Bitmap`. Create the new `Bitmap` independently, pass it to `FromImage` then return the new `Bitmap`.

```
var edit = new Bitmap(bm.Width, bm.Height);
// ...
using (Graphics imagesGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(edit))
{
    // draw original
    // draw watermark
}
return edit;
```